# Not able to create database on server

Tags: mysql

I have tried to create database on server by `CREATE DATABASE cpi_mock` but getting an error like `#1044 - Access denied for user 'cpibetap'@'localhost' to database 'cpi_mock'`. Then I try to execute `SHOW GRANTS` It gives me something like

`Grants for cpibetap@localhost`
     `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'cpibetap'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<password>'`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `cpibetap\_%`.* TO 'cpibetap'@'localhost'
```

Can anyone tell me what is meaning of above lines? How can I create database on my server?

Answer (score 0):

If the user only have USAGE privilege it does not have access to create the database.

You write "It gives me something like", can you paste the actual response?

The Grant all statements is for the user cpibetap_%, the _ requires a character and the username is only cpibetap thus not having any extra character.